# How to show WooCommerce price variations in product loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On my WooCommerce shop, I'm showing my prices ex VAT. Now I also want to show the price inc VAT. Therefore, I have set up the following code:

```
    // Add price inc VAT to products loop
    function wbgoe_show_price_inc_VAT()
    {
        global $product;
        ?>
<span class="price">
    <?php echo wc_price(wc_get_price_including_tax($product)) . " <small class='woocommerce-price-suffix'>(" . __('inc. BTW', 'tendotools') . ")</small>"; ?>
</span>
<?php }

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wbgoe_show_price_inc_VAT');


// Add price inc VAT to single product
function wbgoe_show_price_inc_VAT_sp()
{
    global $product; ?>
<p class="price">
    <?php echo wc_price(wc_get_price_including_tax($product)) . " <small class='woocommerce-price-suffix'>(" . __("inc. BTW", "tendotools") . ")</small>"; ?>
</p>
<?php }

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wbgoe_show_price_inc_VAT_sp');
```

My issue is that for variable products, the price is showing only the lowest price instead of the price variation as well. https://prnt.sc/q526ls

What is the proper code to print the price variation inc VAT?